# How to see the full name of a field in TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, workitem

I am trying to setup a config file to work with my TFS Fields and I am having problems finding the full name of a field.

For example, In the query view I just see *Delivery Order*, but I know that it's full name is *Conchango.TeamSystem.Scrum.DeliveryOrder*.

Anyidea how I can see that value for all the fields on my Work Items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install the [TFS Power Tool](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/3e8c9b68-6e39-4577-b9b7-78489b5cb1da) you will get the process template editor. If you open the Work Item that you want to see the fields for in there you will get a list of all the fields.

[image: Select "Tools | Process Editor | Work Item Types | Open WIT from Server"]
**Figure: Select "Tools | Process Editor | Work Item Types | Open WIT from Server"**

[image: Connect to the correct TFS server and select a project]
**Figure: Connect to the correct TFS server and select a project**

[image: You can see the list of fields]
**Figure: You can see the list of fields**

It is worth noting that the Label used on the Work Item Form may be diferent from the actual name of the field.